# How do you perform a delayed loop in Opa?

Tags: opa

What construct exists in Opa to perform a delayed loop; for instance, executing a function every 10 seconds.

Take the chatroom tutorial - if I wanted a bot in there then how would I have it write a statement every 10 seconds to the other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`Scheduler`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#scheduler.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Scheduler) module. In particular the: [`Scheduler.timer`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#scheduler.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Scheduler.timer) function, or [`Scheduler.make_timer`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/index.html#scheduler.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.core.rpc.core.Scheduler.make_timer) if you need more control over your timer (like stopping or changing the interval).